# Next JS firebase TypeError: firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.storage is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
```

Already added the firestore import here so that fixed most of everybody elses problem

```
const clienteCredentials = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

export default function initFirebase() {
  if (!firebase.apps.length){
      firebase.initializeApp(clienteCredentials);
  }
}
```

Keeps getting the error here:

```
    const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
    const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();


export { projectFirestore, projectStorage };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Firebase `V9.0.0+` then you can use `compat` version to keep using existing code (V8 name-spaced syntax):

```
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/storage"
import "firebase/comapt/firestore"
```

I'd recommend [upgrading to new Modular Syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) which has certain benefits and supports tree-shaking. The newer syntax looks like:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app" // no compat
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage"

const app = initializeApp({...config})

const firestore = getFirestore(app)
const storage = getStorage(app)
```

Do checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) which has examples of both older and newer syntaxes.

Comment: Thank you, that was definitely it. Didn't know nothing about the new syntaxes, it all makes sense now! Life Savior

Comment: done, thank you again. Saved me from a lot of headaches haha

Comment: Saved my day. Nice!